# How to bind an iframe with 'on' method in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, iframe, jquery-on

Bind an iframe with **on** method in jquery.

I am using jquery mobile lib with an iframe in page.

```
$(frame).contents().on('tap', 'div', function() { console.info('sucess')} )}
```

How to bind the iframe with **on** method?

Here I tried to get **tap** function bind to iframe contents with **on** method.

```
//Structure of HTML page

<div  data-role="page" id="test" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c" style="min-height: 491px;">
    <iframe height="491" frameborder="0" width="100%" src="about:blank" name="test">
        // ...
        <div id="one" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                // Contents
            </div>
        </div>
        // ...
    </iframe>
</div>
```

The **click**  method 
`$(frame).contents().click(function(e) { alert('sucess'); })` will work. But when it comes with mobile device **click** method doesn't works...

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set an ID to the iFrame and bind on it like this :

`$('#iFrameId).on('tap', 'div', function() { console.info('sucess'); });`

Remember that you NEED to create your event binding in the script included in the **first** page loaded with JQuery mobile. By design, all JS scripts included in other files loaded later are ignored.

Comment: Thanks for response. But It didn't works, I have my script in first page itself. This will work with **click** like below `$(frame).contents().click(function(e) { alert('sucess'); })`. But when it comes with mobile device **click** method doesn't works...

Answer (score 0):

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ugufoh/9)

you need attach the handler to iframe's contentDocument:

```
$($frame[0].contentDocument).on('click', '#tap', function(){
    alert('success');
});
```

Comment: How would we write a tap here?. `$($frame[0].contentDocument).on('tap', '#tap', function(){`. This will not works...

Comment: Thanks for your effort... :-)